# Is it possible or feasible to use the FDW extension from a local database to Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm facing a situation where I have two PostgreSQL databases, one local and one in Cloud SQL. Some tables from the local database should be somewhat replicated in the cloud and vice-versa (it is not the case for an exact replica of the whole database, just part of it).

In this case, is it possible (or feasible performance-wise) to use the FDW extension from PostgreSQL to allow the access of the data from both ways? If not, what are some alternatives to replicate only parts of the database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a functionality like the [external master replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master) for mySQL? [According to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-external-master), this is not yet supported in PostgreSQL, and according to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79240971), this is intended behavior.

Comment: Yes, I think I would actually need the logical replication functionality, but that is also not supported by Cloud SQL PostgreSQL at the moment. The FDW extension would be useful to allow access between the databases, but as you pointed out, I can't rely on that for now. Thanks for your answer. I might create a new question in SO regarding alternatives to logical replication in Cloud SQL PostgreSQL. Thanks for your answer, @Jofre.

Comment: @Jofre Post your answer as a solution, please, so we can "keep the forum ordered".

Comment: @RubénC. Done!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: CloudSQL now accepts FDW. [Docs here.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#postgres_fdw)

---

There is a limited list of [allowed PostgreSQL extensions on Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions), and at the moment of writing this answer none of them are for [FDW](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers).

In the use case you described, a functionality similar to the [Cloud SQL First Gen mySQL external master replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master) would be interesting, but for PostgreSQL [this functionality is not yet supported](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-external-master).

In Google's issue tracker there are Feature Requests for both the [external master in PostgreSQL](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79240971) and the [support for FDW extensions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37570439) ([and also this duplicate issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80326621)), although it looks like the external master feature request has been marked as *working as intended*, so I'm guessing you should not expect this feature any time soon. The feature request for FDW extensions seem to be gaining some traction, so I would suggest to [follow that issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) to get any update.

Comment: Google has since then added postgres_fdw to Google Cloud SQL